# Show and hide div with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css, vb.net

I have a problem to show and hide some div.
The only thing i have is a span with a class. Where we need to click on, to show or hide the div below the parent h2
I can't add some classe's to the h2 or div (this come from some cms, where we can't add a css class), so we need to do it with some jquery.

```
<div>
  <h2>
    <span class="h2toggle">Heading (This shows an hide the div below)</span>
  </h2>
  <div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>More text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>
    <span class="h2toggle">Heading 2 (This shows an hide the div below)</span>
  </h2>
  <div>
    <p>Some text 2</p>
    <p>More text 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now i have something like the following code.
But now, when the page will be loaded. The div around "some text" & "more text" will we hidden.
But you can see that it is not hidden from the beginning. It's sliding up.

It should be hidden ( the div with text ) from the beginning. Without seeing any change to the page.
After that the page is loaded, it must be possible to toggle on the headings.

```
(function ($) {
$(function () {
    $('.h2toggle').each(function () {
        $(this).parent('h2').addClass('h2toggle');
        $(this).removeClass('h2toggle');
        $(this).parent().siblings(':not(h2):visible').slideUp()
    });

    $('.h2toggle').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings(':not(h2):visible').slideUp()
        $(this).siblings(':not(h2):hidden').slideDown()
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: After a first look... you are missing many semicolons '** ; **'

Comment: @roXon: Not required in JS, however. ;-)

Comment: Brad ... thanks! I know it won't throw a disgusting error. But... ah, whatever. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo using ternary operators:

### [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/SMxYH/3/)

And it will act as a beautiful Accordion! (If other content is opened.. close it!)

```
$('.h2toggle').parent().next('div').hide();
$('.h2toggle').click(function() {
    var d = $(this).parent('h2').next('div');
 check = (d.is(':visible')) ?
         (d.slideUp()) :
         ($('.h2toggle').parent('h2').next('div').slideUp()) (d.slideDown());
});
```

In this case, how ternary operators work:

```
_____statement___    __is is true_      __________________is false______________________________________________
|                |   |            |    |      (do that)                                          (and that too) |
(d.is(':visible')) ? ( d.slideUp() ) : ( $('.h2toggle').parent('h2').next('div').slideUp() )   ( d.slideDown() );
```

... And you'll get the smallest script to get an accordion!
Happy coding!

Comment: roXon , it likes that this is working. But i can't change the classe's on span and div. So it must work on the code i wrote above.

Comment: Than [THIS link](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/SMxYH/3/) is what you need (reedited my answer)

Comment: It works, but only in IE7 there is a small delay ( You see some slide-up). Do you know why?

Comment: Tested in IE7, can't see the delay.

Answer (score 4):

Erm...easy?

```
$('.h2toggle').click(function(){
    var $span = $(this);

    $span.parent('h2').next('div').slideToggle();
});
```

[Demo, btw](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/TPes6/)

To make them start hidden, use [the following](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/TPes6/1/):

```
$('.h2toggle').parent('h2').next('div').slideUp();
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding... Reference the H2, then grab the next div (which is declared below) and toggle its display.

*If you want this more like a "show only one at a time" accordion, then I can revise the code, but I'm not interpreting it like that.*

Comment: Start hidden is not correct. That's just the point. :) You may not see the animation on the beginning.

Comment: @SvenVdb: Then create a style that is essentially `.init-hide { display: none; }` then, on load, call `$('.h2toggle').parent().next('div').addClass('init-hide');` and it will be hidden off-the-bat. Better yet, place that code in-line after the block(s) and it won't wait for the page to render before being called.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are sliding everything up and then sliding everything down:

```
$('.h2toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings(':not(h2):visible').slideUp()
    $(this).siblings(':not(h2):hidden').slideDown()
});
```

Perhaps this would work:

```
$('.h2toggle').click(function () {
    var visibleStuff = $(this).siblings(':not(h2):visible');
    var hiddenStuff = $(this).siblings(':not(h2):hidden').slideDown();

    visibleStuff.slideUp();
    hiddenStuff.slideDown();
});
```

Brad Christie is right, though... you just need to toggle.

```
$('.h2toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings(':not(h2)').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Slide is doing an animation, eventually hiding the element. Use Hide instead:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $('.h2toggle').parent().next('div').hide();
        $('.h2toggle').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Start hidden is not correct. That's just the point. :) You may not see the animation on the beginning.